# Need to send reminder mail one day before using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I need to send a reminder mail one day before the task date. I know about this thing can be done by using cron job.

For example, If my friends birthday is on 04-feb-2011 i need to receive a reminder mail on 03-feb-2011.

I am having all the details in the mysql database.

EDIT:

**But is stored the birthday date the following format**

**--> birthDay :  Wed Feb 09 2011 00:00:00 GMT+ 0530 (India Standard Time)**

**how do i compare now in this case?**

**But could any one tell me how the query should be?**

Any help will be grateful and thankful..

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

you need to run a cron job every day, in this cron job you check who has a birthday tomorrow.

the query is like:

```
select * from mytable where 
date = DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```